# Arrow function is not a function. is an instance of Array. React-native hooks

Tags: javascript, react-native, hook

I got this hook setup that uses sockets

```
import { useEffect, useState, useRef, useContext } from 'react';
import useSocket from './useSocket';

export default useMarkers = () => {
  const [markers, setMarkers] = useState([]);
  const [socket] = useSocket();

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('all markers', allMarkers => {
      setMarkers([...allMarkers]);
    });
  }, [setMarkers]);


  const addMarker = marker => {
    socket.emit('add marker', marker);
  };


  return [markers, addMarker];
};
```

Then I'm trying to call the addMarker function in one of my other hooks like:

```
const [addMarker] = useMarkers();

addMarker(address);
...
```

However, I'm getting an error:

```
addMarker is not a function. (In 'addMarker(address)', 'addMarker' is an instance of Array)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array destructuring, unlike object destructuring, doesn't retain variable names (because arrays don't have names for keys, they have numbers). So when you do:

```
const [addMarker] = useMarkers();
```

You are assigning `markers` to `addMarker`:

```
return [markers, addMarker];
           |
           |
           v
const  [addMarker] = useMarkers();
```

The confusion comes from the fact that there are two separate variables both called `addMarker` that refers to different things.

To fix it assign the second element to `addMarker`:

```
const [ ignored, addMarker ] = useMarkers();
```

Or use object destructuring:

```
return { markers, addMarker }

// then later:

const { addMarker } = useMarkers();
```

Comment: Such an obvious mistake, thanks for pointing this out. Tunnel vision :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the array you're returning:

> return [markers, addMarker];

The **first** element in it is the `markers` array. The **second** element in it is the `addMarker` function.

> const [addMarker] = useMarkers();

Here you're assigning the **first** element to `addMarker` and **discarding** the second element.

---

Array destructuring is based on **index** not the name of the variable that was used to populate the array in the first place.